# How to create a corner ribbon on react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm stuck on creating a corner ribbon on a card. Before I used `react-native-svg` library to do this task. but having an issue with the library. How can I do it without using any library? is there a way to do it from CSS?

the ribbon is look like this.

[image]

Comment: `svg` are the best option. Use an image instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute position for placement and transform to rotate. Something like this:

```
const Banner = ({message, style}) => {
  return (
    <Text style={[styles.banner, style]}>
      {message}
    </Text>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  banner: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: -40,
    top: 20,
    width: 160,
    transform: [{ rotate: "45deg" }],
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: 'white',
    padding: 8,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Image 
        source={{uri: 'https://picsum.photos/1080/1920'}} 
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
      />
      <Banner 
        message="PREMIUM" 
        style={{
          color: 'black', 
          backgroundColor: 'yellow', 
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

See [Transforms](https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms#methods) for details.